# Sometimes not receiving ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL events

Tags: android, user-interface, android-animation

I created an app with buttons that shrink when pressed to simulate a physical button being pressed down. The buttons function as intended, but in real-life testing with users, it was discovered that sometimes the button does not return to its original size (occurring about 5% of the time).

The cause of this unexpected behavior is unknown and any insights would be appreciated. Our current assumption is that the `ACTION_UP || ACTION_CANCEL` is not being triggered in some rare scenarios, but we are uncertain.

```
public class MainActivity extends CustomActivity
{
    public AppCompatButton myButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.my_button);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(myClickListener); // handle the actual click
        myButton.setOnTouchListene(myTouchListener); // simulate press down
    }

    ...

    private View.OnTouchListener myTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            int action = event.getAction();

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "scaleX", 0.7f);
                ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "scaleY", 0.7f);

                scaleDownX.setDuration(120);
                scaleDownY.setDuration(120);

                AnimatorSet scaleDown = new AnimatorSet();
                scaleDown.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY);

                scaleDown.start();
            }
            
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
            {
                ObjectAnimator scaleUpX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "scaleX", 1);
                ObjectAnimator scaleUpY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "scaleY", 1);

                scaleUpX.setDuration(100);
                scaleUpY.setDuration(100);

                AnimatorSet scaleUp = new AnimatorSet();
                scaleUp.play(scaleUpX).with(scaleUpY);

                scaleUp.start();
            }

            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. It was discovered that `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_CANCEL` were being called, but the problem was with the interaction between `scaleDown.start();` and `scaleUp.start();`.

If they were executed immediately after each other, `scaleUp.start();` did not automatically cancel the animations of `scaleDown.start();`, leaving the button stuck in the "down" position. The issue was resolved by using Facebook's Spring library.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code. It's working perfectly for me. If you still getting issues with it, I suggest you to use 
[Rebound - Spring animations for android](http://facebook.github.io/rebound/)

Comment: Again, I emphasize on only sometimes (5%) - the unpredictable nature of the problem is what is causing us issues

Comment: Did u checked the OS version of the devices causing problem ? Or is it showing issues randomly ?

Comment: Entirely random, just sometimes happens, sometimes doesn't. It should also be noted that this phenomena only occurs when testing on real devices and not on the emulator

Comment: I'll check in my different devices. Will update If I get any solution.

Comment: Hey, I found another symptom. It seems to be related to multi-touch somehow. When you mash all your fingers on multiple buttons lined up side by side this occurs. Still we are not sure why its happening like this.

Comment: Good to know that the issue is solved by using facebook's spring library.
:)